# Why Redux.js launches reducer function multiple times on init?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Learning Redux.js and building a demo app.

I have a reducer set like this:

```
// Imports here
function blocksFunc(state = [], action) {

  switch (action.type) {

  case 'ADD_BLOCK':

    _id++;
    return [...state, {'_class' : 'basic', '_id' : _id }];

  default:

    state = []; 
    return state;
  }
}

const BlockGeneratorReducer = combineReducers({

  blocksFunc,
});

export default BlockGeneratorReducer;
```

I successfully update the state, but when logging I get the following when page loads:

> blocksFunc() type: "@@redux/INIT"
>
> blocksFunc() type:
>   "@@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION_b.f.4.q.y.o.a.v.2.t.9"
>
> blocksFunc() type: "@@redux/INIT"

So blocksFunc function is launched three times with default action.type. On which occasions is the action type "@@redux/INIT" launched? What might "@@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTIOM" refer in to?

The full source can be found on git: https://github.com/JaakkoKarhu/redux-react-blockgenerator

The working demo is uploaded to my server: http://jaakkokarhu.com/playground/redux-block-generator/

Since being new with React and Redux, all the other comments regarding the source are also very welcome.

EDIT:

blocksFunc() edited according to DavidWalshes advice.

Comment: The "dot dot dot" is the spread operator. It rips out the elements of the array that follows into separate arguments. e.g. f(...[a,b,c]) is the equivalent of f(a,b,c).

Don't use state.push(). You must never mutate your state in Redux. You should instead have:
return [...state, {'_class' : 'basic', '_id' : _id }];

Comment: why are you setting the state to an empty array when an unknown action is encountered?

Comment: @TenorB Oh, actually no reason for that and it doesn't matter much since this demo is just for fooling around. But good point tho, I wasn't really even thinking of it before.

Comment: See [this warning message](https://github.com/unindented/immutable-redux/blob/7437ff38c885d09f1c5dbe628ddd84c091d6899d/src/utils/combineImmutableReducers.js#L73) to see why the probe actions are dispatched. The purpose is to test whether your reducer is properly handling unknown actions.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

@@redux/INIT is launched twice on purpose. First time is for testing combineReducers, second one is actual init: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/382

As TenorB pointed out on question comments, @@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION is also launched for testing purpose.

So, after all, these events are not accidentally launched.

Comment: Ok then, so the answer is "that is default behaviour". Is that correct?

Comment: @EliseChant As far as I know, yes.